# Algorithm for matching fractional demand and supply volumes

Tags: algorithm, optimization, combinatorics, knapsack-problem

**Problem:** There is a marketplace for buying and selling widgets, and the widgets are divisible (e.g. flour). At any point in time, there may be a total of X widgets listed for sale by S sellers, and Y total widget purchase requests by B buyers. The system needs to continuously watch, and as soon as demand >= supply, it fulfills as many demands as possible until the supply is exhausted. Then it starts watching again, continuing with any left-over demands.

This problem *seems* to be similar to the *continuous multiple Knapsack* problem, and also the *Bin packing* problem (except that I am not minimizing the number of bins) and again to me it seems similar to the *k-Partition* problems - but I need more information on the algorithm, or some pseudocode to learn how to do this effectively.

**Proposed idea:** Combine all supplies into one knapsack, use the [fractional / continuous knapsack method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_knapsack_problem) to sell to as many buyers (best offers - based on unit cost - are taken first) as possible, and then finally partition that large knapsack into smaller knapsacks (one for each seller). Is this the most effective method?

***Case 2:*** Also, how do I approach this if the widgets all cost the same?

Comment: I'm afraid that this description is not enough. I don't  get why this is going towards any of those NP-hard base-problems (which are all discrete-optimization problems). Looks more like a simple network-flow problem (if reaching this level of complexity at all).

Comment: @sascha You know what they say - if all you know is a hammer, everything looks like a nail. Sorry I am only familiar with those ones. Please can you help describe the network-flow approach you are talking about?